# Triple volume integral that resembles surface integrals, substitution or Gauss' Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, volume, substitution

Preparing to enter graduate schools in mathematics, I have come across this volume integral

\begin{array}{c}
\iiint_{V} \frac{1}{\left(1+x^{2}+y^{2}\right) z^{3 / 2}} d x d y d z \\
V=\left\{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \leq z\right\}.
\end{array}

It definitely appears as if prepared for a simplification through a surface integral, integrating the volume over z between two surfaces.
That is, using the theory behind Gauss' (Divergence) Theorem.
However, I am not sure as how to approach it.
I.e. how exactly to fit it into said theorem or a coordinate transformation.
Neither a polar transformation nor the theorem directly seem to reasonably simplify it.

It also seems that this type of integral can be solved through a clever substitution, that is other substitution than the standard.

Anybody up for help?
Thanks.

Comment: I think you're giving up on polar too quickly, cylindrical looks completely fine here

Comment: In cylindrical coordinates, you have $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \int_{r^2}^{\infty} \frac{r} {(1+r^2) \cdot z^{3/2}} \ dz \ dr \ d\theta \ $, which is straightforward to evaluate and you should get $2 \pi^2$.

Comment: Oh yes, one may use cylindrical and that's how they may keep z intact, integrating the rest as polar.
I have also looked up other transformations and e.g., the generalized spherical coordinates may be used to elegantly transform out some other problems I have been stuck at.
This has helped me progress greatly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite in cylindrical coordinates: let $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta, z = z$. Our one bound for $z$ turns into $z \geq r^2$.

So we have:

$$\iiint_V \frac{1}{(1 + x^2 + y^2)z^{\frac{3}{2}}} dV = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{r^2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1 + r^2)z^{\frac{3}{2}}} r dz dr d\theta$$

$$=2\pi\int_0^{\infty} \frac{r}{1+r^2} \Bigg[-\frac{2}{z^{\frac{1}{2}}}\Bigg]^{\infty}_{r^2}dr = 4\pi\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+r^2} dr = 4\pi\cdot\frac{\pi}{2} = 2\pi^2.$$